# How to get rendered text from controls or text contained by a custom control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a control that will display text from a database field.  If the field does not contain any data, I would like to provide it default content to use, which I want to set to the DB field and render to the page.  Not a terribly complex thing, I'm just having trouble getting the contents of the tag.

Example:

```
<custom:foo runat="server">this is the default content</custom:foo>
```

I would like to be able to grab any markup between the custom:foo tags and render that to a string that I can store in the DB field.

I know the easy way to do this is to just create a DefaultContent property and set it that way, but I like the flexibility to place more than just text inside the control and render it.

I've tried using Me.RenderChildren into an HtmlTextWriter and all I get from the above example is `"<span></span>"`

```
        Dim Builder As New StringBuilder()
        Using Writer As New StringWriter(Builder)
            Using HtmlWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(Writer)
                Me.RenderChildren(HtmlWriter)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return Builder.ToString()
```

Has anyone had any success with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `ParseChildren` attribute, and then override the OnRender method to output HTML accordingly.

Eg. something like this:

**Control**

```
namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    [ParseChildren]
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
            private string m_MyText;

            public string MyText
            {
                    get { return m_MyText; }
                    set { m_MyText = value; }
            }

            protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyText))
                    {
                            writer.Write("Value of MyText: " + MyText);
                            return;
                    }

                    base.Render(writer);
            }
    }
}
```

**ASPX Page**

```
<!--Displays "Hello World!"-->
<MyApp:MyControl runat="server">Hello World!</MyApp:MyControl>

<!--Displays "Value of MyText: Hello" -->
<MyApp:MyControl MyText="Hello" runat="server">Hello World!</MyApp:MyControl>

<!--Displays Red Text-->
<MyApp:MyControl runat="server"><asp:Label Text="Red Text" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" /></MyApp:MyControl>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I am using VB and needed to use this as the attribute: <ParseChildren(False)>  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an ID on the custom:foo control so you can access it from the code behind?

Comment: I have not. I'm trying to keep all of the logic inside the custom:foo control so the code-behind's of any page it is used on never need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out
ViewManager.RenderView

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx