# Is there any way to get raw text from a custom templated control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating a very simple templated custom control, like:

```
Public Class MyControl
Inherits Control
Implements INamingContainer

<TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Multiple)> _
<TemplateContainer(GetType(MyTemplateContainer))> _
<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
<Browsable(True)> _
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _

Public Property ContentTemplate() As ITemplate
    Get
        Return m_ContentTemplate
    End Get
    Set(value As ITemplate)
        m_ContentTemplate = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ContentTemplate As ITemplate
```

I'm overriding CreateChildControls()

```
Protected Override Sub CreateChildControls()
' I have access to Me.ContentTemplate but can't figure out how to read it.

End Sub
```

And in my page:

```
<hello:MyControl runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        I want this text
    </ContentTemplate>
</hello:MyControl>
```

This is obviously not all my code, but basically using ITemplate. I want to be able to grab everything entered between the opening and closing ContentTemplate tags.

Failed with this: [How to get rendered text from controls or text contained by a custom control in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789453/how-to-get-rendered-text-from-controls-or-text-contained-by-a-custom-control-in)

And this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx

I basically need that raw text, no matter what it is... div tags, span tags, just text, just ... whatever is in it.

I have to be missing something simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of ITemplate in custom control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442535/usage-of-itemplate-in-custom-control)

Comment: It looks like inheriting from `WebControl` instead of `Control` should make this work, though you still have extra work you need to do to actually create the child controls.  See the answer to the duplicate question.